# Unable to reinstall webform second time

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

1. initially i used webform 7.x-4.1 installed. webform ajax (7.x-1.1) not worked, so i just uninstalled web form and webform ajax.
2. manually deleted following tables,

> DROP TABLE `webform` , `webform_component` , `webform_conditional` ,
>   `webform_conditional_rules` , `webform_emails` ,
>   `webform_last_download` , `webform_roles` , `webform_submissions` ,
>   `webform_submitted_data` ;

3. again i tried web form 7.x-3.20 installation. but i getting bellow error.

   PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mydb.webform' doesn't exist: SELECT w.*, n.title AS title FROM {webform} w LEFT OUTER JOIN {node} n ON w.nid = n.nid WHERE (w.block = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (n.type IN (:db_condition_placeholder_1)) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 1 [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => webform ) in webform_block_info() (line 1697 of C:\wamp\www\\sites\all\modules\webform\webform.module).

tell me the steps by step to uninstall the web form and web form ajax. i want to install web form (7.x-3.20 ) and web ajax once again

Comment: Why did deleted the table manually?

Comment: Ouch... What you did is risky. I hope you did a DB backup before.

Comment: @VladStratulat bcoz uninstall process does not removed the tables, when install different version webform. i getting error  like unknown coumn serial. this serial column does not exist in the prev version web form module

Comment: @Djouuuuh i have tried with local installation only. so i didn't took  db bak-up

Comment: How did you uninstalled the 7.x-4.1 version? Did you just disabled the module? If yes: disabling is not the same as uninstalling.

Answer (score 0):

I've also manually deleted stuff in the past and its kind of complicated to get rid of everything that way.

1. Check that you've drop every table called webform*
2. Clear the cache
3. Check under admin/modules/uninstall so there is nothing left of webform
4. Clear the cache
5. Remove sites/all/modules/webform
6. Clear the cache
7. Clear the cache (with drush)
8. Clear the cache (with your left hand (if youre righthanded (otherwise the other way around)))
9. Reinstall the correct modules

I hope it works

Comment: 3rd point failed for me, after table deleted still is displaying in the uninstall tab